# tesseract python The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tesseract

I am running a python test framework that uses Tesseract.

When I run a test that uses tesseract however I get the following error :

`WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

I managed to go through the logs and found it breaks at:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
```

The subprocess is called by a non python lib command from the framework

```
def process_frame_text(single_char=False):
    tess_list = ['tesseract', 'tmp/ocr_image.png', 'tmp/ocr_output']
    tess_list += ['-psm', '10'] if single_char else []
    check_output(tess_list, stderr=STDOUT)[:-1]
```

I have installed windows Tesseract on my machine at C:\Program Files x86\Tesseract-OCR

Appreciate you ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, `subprocess` module is not able to find `tesseract.exe` and invoke it from Windows shell. If path to the executable, `C:\Program Files x86\Tesseract-OCR`,  is not added to `Windows environment variables`, then modify `tess_list` to provide full file path.

**EDIT:**

For your case, should set:

- `TESSDATA_PREFIX` = `C:\Program Files x86\Tesseract\tessdata` that points to the trained language data files.
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR` which is the `tesseract.exe` file path should be added to Windows system `PATH` variable as an addition value, such as
  `PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR"` if added by
  command for temporary use.

Comment: Thats exactly what the problem is, thank you. Ive added the path directly.

Comment: It is already an environment variable TESSDATA_PREFIX: C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe so im going to investigate why that doesnt work

Comment: @mogoli, check my additional info in Answer under EDIT. Your `TESSDATA_PREFIX` setting is incorrect.

Comment: Worked for me, I just did the second bullet after the "EDIT"